# Trouble with getting a CouchApp to output the correct mime type for an appcache

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchapp, couchdb-futon

So in CouchDB, you can supposedly change mime types. In Futon you just have to go and edit the source of the document and change the content_type field on attachments in the _attachment field. Trouble is, when I do this so that an appcache file has the correct mime type (text/cache-manifest), and save the document, it doesn't save and the content_type field is just blank again "". Any tips on outputing the right mime type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, that *is* weird.

You can work-around this problem by adding a `Content-Type: text/cache-manifest` header when you store the attachment.

I think this will not work from a browser because it overrides the Content-Type. You can use curl from the command-line to upload an attachment. You need to know the document's current `_rev` revision value.

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/cache-manifest" \
     --data-binary @/path/to/appcache/file         \
     http://localhost:5984/db/the_doc/cache.manifest?rev=123-abcdef
```

Answer (score 3):

The _attachments object is not user editable, which explains why your update did not work as expected. The most you can do with _attachments is to remove attachments completely by removing them from the object.

Comment: Consider if you could edit the digest value or the length, etc. Allowing an edit to the attachment name or content-type makes sense. If you filed a ticket on our JIRA, it could happen. :)

Comment: I think there is an additional bug that CouchDB silently ignores your changes. It returns 201 Created. You have a new `_rev` value, etc. That was the most shocking part.

Comment: Wasn't the checksum stuff recently-added? Before that, there was no way to meaningfully rename attachments because it is just a big set of filenalme/metadata key-val pairs. With the new md5 checksum field, I suppose an implementation is possible, perhaps not convenient for the implementor :)

Comment: Closest JIRA ticket I could find is: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-715